# Unable to install Parrot Security OS 4.0.1

Tags: linux, boot, parrot-os

I am trying to install Parrot Security Edition Version 4.0.1 and I downloaded the iso from the parrot website. I also downloaded the preferred `iso_extractor` and tried a couple of others but I keep getting the same problem. When I boot from the flash drive and go to the installation option, the screen prints `Quit\\\\\\\Quit\\\\\\` all the time. So, what am I doing wrong and what should I do to install it correctly on my machine?

> NOTE: I am still able to boot using the live mode but there is no option to install it from the live mode.

Answer (score 0):

Possible actions :

1. Re-download and try again.
2. If no go, try using another ISO tool. You don't usually need to extract
   anything, just open the ISO in the file manager.
3. Ask your question on the Parrot Project
   [Community Portal](https://docs.parrotsec.org/community).